# tea bag flavors mixing algorithm

Tags: algorithm

I bought tree boxes of tea bags with differents flavors (A, B, C).

I wish to mix them in such a way that - there is never two consecutive bags of the same flavor (ABCCAB is avoided) ; - the mixing is the "most" random, i.e. avoid patterns such as ABCABCABC... or ABABAB...BCBCBC...CACACA.

Is there a known algorithm for this mix ?

Presently I randomly shuffle many "ABC" and concatenate the results, swapping the first letters if the latest letter of the previous shuffle is the same than the beginning of the new shuffle (...ABCCAB => ...ABCACB).

I guess I could improve this algorithm by pre-computing the permutations of ABC, and draw one permutations among the ones who do not begin with the same letter than the previous permutation.

I tried to "google" this problem but as a French native speaker, I probably miss the appropriate key-words.

PS : I posted this question on scicomp.stackexchange.com previously, and being advised to duplicate it here.

Comment: Another crosspost suggestion since you already have a working solution would be the [CodeReview SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Can you clarify whether you're currently generating as much triplets of values as there are teabags of a single flavour, which you join afterward? In particular, should a solution produce the whole sequence or just a way to provide the next bag of tea?

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "most random". I think you mean "looks random" by which you mean there's no obvious patterns. Or perhaps you mean that each sequence with no repeated letters is equally likely? If you mean the former, it's not really a well-specified problem.

Comment: Thanks- Done. By the way, I am fairly new to stack* : is there a way to crosspost as in usenet ?

Comment: For aaron : as there are the same numbers of bags in each box, I generate this number of triplets. I join a new triplet to the previous one, and swap the two first elements of the new triplet if the first one is the same that the third one of the previous triplet. By the way, it could be done with n-uplets. I need to produce the whole sequence. Another use of this algorithm is to generate "call to chalkboard" list of my students.

Comment: In general, cross posting seems to be frowned upon on StackExchange, especially the more technical sites. If you post on one site and moderators/the community think a better site is appropriate, your question is likely to be migrated.

Comment: @Dominique do answer need to improve on the lack of randomness that being sure that every triplet { n, n+1, n+2 } where n = x*3 contains a single value of every choice represents, or is it okay with you? I tried to avoid that in my answer, but as you can see from my edit it leads to more complication since there's the risk that you would exhaust two choices faster than the third one.

Comment: Without a clearer definition of "most random", there's no way to answer this question. Statistically, "ABABAB" is exactly as likely a random outcome as "ABCACB".

Comment: For Paul Hankin : I agree "most random" is not clear. I guess from complexity theory that I expect a non redundant sequence at any scale. Not possible as there can be not enough permutations, compared to the numbers of bags in one box. I guess this expectation is close to "no obvious pattern".

Comment: @Aaron : my algorithms garantee that each triplet contains a single value of each choice, but it is not mandatory.  But it would be boring to drink the same flavour again and again at the end of the sequence :-).

Comment: @Sneftel : I agree.  For example ABCABC is most predictable than ABCACB or ABACBC so the former is less desirable as more boring  . By the way there is no C in "ABABAB".

Comment: Would you consider "ABCACBBACBCACABCBA" to be a fairly random string, given that it's just all six permutations of "ABC", concatenated in lexical order? If you count that as random, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_repeated_substring_problem . If not, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov_complexity .

Comment: @sneftel  : There are two consecutive B. But it is a near perfect random string. I tried this manually and was unable to concatenate the six permutations of "ABC" without repetition at one boundary.

Comment: @sneffel : Longest repeated substring problem provides a criterion for a srting being the longest possible without repetition, but not how to generate it. This "path" is nethertheless interesting as it could be a criterion for an optimization algoritm (genetic algorithm ?).

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should work :

```
amount_of_teabags_per_flavour = x
choices = {
    A : amount_of_teabags_per_flavour,
    B : amount_of_teabags_per_flavour,
    C : amount_of_teabags_per_flavour
}
previous_choice = 0
picks_left = amount_of_teabags_per_flavour * choices.size

function select_available_choices() :
    mandatory_choice = [ key from choices where key != previous_choice and value <= picks_left/2 ] 
    if mandatory_choice == [] :
        available_choices = [ key from choices where key != previous_choice and value > 0 ]
    otherwise
        available_choices = mandatory_choice


result = []
select_available_choices()
while available_choices != [] :
    choice = pick_randomly_from(available_choices)
    result[last] = choice
    previous_choice = choice
    choices[choice]--
    picks_left--
    select_available_choices()
```

Comment: This answer was one of my avenue (is this correct for "path" or "way") to improve my algorithms. I sensed the risk of exhausting two flavours before the third one has only one remaining bag. May be would it be possible to bias randomness in favor of  the most available flavour.

Comment: It might be enough to force using a choice when its remaining amount is equal to half the total amount (since at this point you need to pick this choice every two picks). I'll see if I can update my solution with this. While it's globally more random than your current solution, it may "feel less random" by the end of the sequence (as in, you'll have less local variation).

Answer (score 0):

You can start with one of the three letters `A`, `B` or `C` at random for the first flavor, then compute the next one from one of the two other possibilities (since you don't want flavors to repeat).

Quick script in python3:

```
from random import randint

rand = lambda x: randint(0,x)

flavors = ['A', 'B', 'C']
freq = [0, 0, 0]

index = rand(2)
mix = flavors[index]

for i in range(1000):
        index = (index + 1 + rand(1)) % 3
        mix += flavors[index]
        freq[index] += 1

print(mix)
print(freq)
```

You can see that the randomness is good (given the frequencies, and a wide enough range) and no character is repeated twice in a row.

Comment: Hum... My tea bag boxes have a finite number of bags.  This leads to unbalanced frequencies, meaning that the sequence is likely to end with the repetition of one flavour. I agree that I can buy another sets of boxes in the aim to reach the infinity :-), but this algorithm has applications for which the number of items is finite : lists of students for example.

Answer (score 0):

Avoiding repetition at the boundary, is a graph problem.  You have a directed edge from each node (permutation) to every other node ... except for the doubled boundary.  You need a **Hamiltonian path** through the graph; solutions are readily available on line.  Then duplicate or truncate that path as much as needed to match the quantity of bags in each box.

If you want to simplify the problem, then generate edges to connect each node *only* with a node that starts with the *second* bag of the previous one.  For instance, with your 3-box design ...

```
ABC -> BAC, BCA
CBA -> BAC, BCA
BAC -> ABC, ACB
CAB -> ABC, ACB
ACB -> CAB, CBA
BCA -> CAB, CBA
```

Any graph built from a full permutation set has a Hamiltonian path, and it's much faster to find.  A simple recursive algorithm (with backtracking) should be easy to code.  If you sort your choices by second-order availability, I *think* the problem solves itself without backtracking.

For instance, if you are at node `ABC`, look at the available choices starting with `B`: `BAC` and `BCA`  Look at the second letters of those: `A` gives you only one remaining choice (`ABC` already got used), but `C` still has two choices.  Therefore, you move to `BCA`.  If your top choices are tied, then decide any way you wish ... preserving your ability to return to the starting node at the end.

Does that solve your problem?